# Are there any good mappings between GCC and MSVC warnings? E.g. -Wredundant-move on MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, warnings

This question is somewhat two fold, one being more general than the other. The specific question is; does MSVC have equivalent warnings to `-Wredundant-move`? More generally, is there anywhere online, even if it's someone's blog, that has a reasonable mapping between GCC and MSVC warnings?

I'm aware that warnings don't have any requirement to be similar accross platforms, or even exist at all - that's why I'm interested to find out if there is any reasonable correlation?

For a small bit of background, I'm looking to enable specific `-Werror`s on a cross-platform project, and would prefer if each platform looked after roughly the same warnings instead of relying on the user to check on both platforms manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The specific question is; does MSVC have equivalent warnings to `-Wredundant-move`?

From what I've found, no, MSVC doesn't.

- The subset of the warning messages that are generated by the Microsoft C/C++ compiler ([Compiler warnings C4000 - C5999](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4000-c5999?view=msvc-170)) does not have any similar warning.
- The [Compiler Warnings by compiler version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-by-compiler-version?view=msvc-170) page does not show one either.
- [Compiler warnings that are off by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/compiler-warnings-that-are-off-by-default?view=msvc-170) is void of such warnings.

This implicitly answers the more general question if there's a good mapping between gcc and MSVC warnings.

But - the future looks promising for the particular kind of warning you asked about:
[Under Review - Pessimizing Move Compiler Warning](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pessimizing-move-compiler-warning/1044200):

> *"LLVM supports a pessimizing-move compiler warning. In C++17 and newer, this fires when invoking std::move() on a temporary, this results in copy elision not occurring on the temporary. This seems a high value warning that is supported in Clang++ and GCC, **but not MSVC**."*

Comment: Thanks for the swift and complete seeming answer. I could wait to see if anyone else thinks they know of a secret compiler option (see one of the warnings pages from your first link "Not every Visual Studio error or warning is documented."), but your answer does agree with my findings and suspicions, and that's good enough for me.

Comment: @Cascades You're welcome! ... and, yes, it's kind of frustrating to not find _"the complete list of MSVC warnings"_ when searching. I'm sure it's out there _somewhere_, but I didn't find it.  I hope my answer becomes "wrong" in a few releases :-)